# Where do the electrons for which RTG's use for the Seeback effect come from?

Tags: isotope, radioactivity

[image]I know that RTG's use Radioactive Isotope that emit Alpha particles generally (ie. NASA uses Pu 238), I also know that these Alpha particles are consiting of 2 Protons and 2 Neutrons, since the RTG has two thermocouple plates that force the protons and the electrons to the cooler side. I was wondering where the electrons come from? Also I was wondering how exactly does the Seeback effect utilize these positive and negative charges with the junction formed to create the electrical charge.

Comment: Did you look at the Wikipedia article on plutonium-238? That isotope has atomic number 94, so it has 94 electrons. When one of those atoms emits an alpha particle, the atom becomes U-234. Since uranium has atomic number 92, it has 92 electrons. And that is where the two electrons come from: 2 = 94 - 92.

Comment: The Pu is contained so the alphas don’t make it to the thermoelectric material. It just gets hot to drive the thermal gradient. No net charge is produced.

Comment: @EdV I was also wondering, in an RTG the electrons come from the decay and not just the free-flowing electrons from the metal of each Semiconductor right (as NASA uses Skutterudite to build the semiconductors)? I was also wondering for the two semiconductors, would one let in protons and the other electrons to create the volage diferential or just electrons for both semiconductors. Please refer to the photo of the diagram above and see if it is accurate. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JonCuster Same question as to EdV above but I was also wondering what material does NASA use in their MMRTG to create the semiconductors, I know they have to be out of two dissimilar metals and read a post on Wikipedia which wrote "The MMRTG design incorporates PbTe/TAGS thermoelectric couples (from Teledyne Energy Systems), where TAGS is an acronym designating a material incorporating tellurium (Te), silver (Ag), germanium (Ge) and antimony (Sb). But that they are trying to use skutterudite, since it needs to be made out of dissimilar metals how would that work?

Comment: Please look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_generator). The decaying Pu-238 yields U-234 plus helium gas. There are no electrons left over: the alpha particle gets two electrons that U-234 cannot hold onto. Alpha particles are powerful oxidizing agents: they can easily oxidize fluorine, for example. They cannot be allowed to oxidize the RTG components. So it is **only the heat** released by the radioactive decay that powers the RTG. As per the linked article, other non-radioactive heat sources can also be used. As for your diagram, I have no idea what it tries to show.

Comment: @EdV Thank you for the clarification, but I was still wondering that to create the voltage differential we have the hotter side ie. the heat from the RTG and the cooler side (space), the atoms vibrate less and scatter towards the colder end, I was wondering in the RTG's is that just electrons, just protons, or one of both in each Thermocouple for each semiconductor, and do they just come from the material of the semiconductor?

Comment: The semiconductors in typical examples are doped N type (so you have donor impurities resulting in electrons are majority charge carriers) and P type (so you have acceptor impurities resulting in positively charged  **holes** as majority charge carriers). No protons are involved. You should do some deeper digging on the Seebeck effect : lots of semiconductor physics books discuss its fundamental principles, and that is more than I can do so long after my last courses on that.

Comment: I just looked up skutterudites and learned they are promising thermoelectric semiconductors. So P and N doped skutterudites are the active elements. Also, a quick search for “seebeck effect” shows some nice cartoons illustrating how the temperature gradient drives both the electrons (in the N type semiconductor) and the holes (in the P type semiconductor) away from the heat source and toward the heat sink. So a potential difference is created and this gives the usable electrical energy output. So heat energy in, electrical energy out. I have nothing further to add.